# Can not externalize a tikz graph with two legend entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, legend

I have a tikz file that contains a matlab scatter plot. It is created by [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz).
The tikz file (sample.tikz) looks as follows and compiles fine in the document without the externalization.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=1, xmax=8,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
legend style={at={(1.03,1)},anchor=north west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
line width=1.5pt
]
table{
0 1.15086549555392
8 1.15086549555392
};
\addlegendentry{baseline};

\addplot[only marks,mark=o,color=green!50!black] plot coordinates{
(1,1.14776993023436)
(2,1.14877635969775)
(3,1.15086549555392)
(4,1.15104679449109)
(5,1.13229950771559)
(6,1.14459533891626)
(7,1.13874295199852)
(8,1.14110592572754)
};
\addlegendentry{$\text{C}_\text{D}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

My tex files looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}               % needed to import .tikz graphics
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}          % needed for tikz scatter plot
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
\newlength\figureheight                 %Tikz plot setup 
\newlength\figurewidth                  %Tikz plot setup

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \setlength\figureheight{0.45\linewidth} 
    \setlength\figurewidth{0.6\linewidth}
    \input{./images/sample.tikz}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compiling it and checking the `./tikz` directory I find an empty `.dpth` file and a `.log` file with the following error:

```
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 34.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \text 

l.34 \end{axis}
```

If I comment out the second `\addlegendentry` in my tikz file it compiles fine and externalizes to the tikz directory. But naturally without the second legend entry.

**Why can't I externalize a tikz file with two legend entries?**

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{amsmath}` to the preamble. `\text` is a macro defined by that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the externalization.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \text
```

means that the command `\text`, that is used in the second legend, is undefined. `\text` is defined in the `amsmath` (well, actually `amstext`) package, so adding

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

to the preamble will fix the error.